# object not available in .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a template of html which i have converted to .aspx format...i have copied all the html code to .aspx, now when i insert any asp item like textbox, button etc in design or .aspx file and double click it but it does not swap over to .cs file and if i go to .cs file and make method for it manually still it does not respond. when i write the object name e.g TextBox1.text so the TextBox1 is underlined with red like the object is not available.
what is the nature and soultion for this problem?

this is aspx code:

```
    <body class="home page page-id-53 page-template page-template-page-properties-grid-php  header-light color-blue pattern-none layout-wide ">

    <div id="wrapper-outer">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="wrapper-inner">
                <div class="header-top-wrapper">
                    <div class="header-top">
                            <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                                                                    <div class="breadcrumb pull-left">
                                                                <!-- Breadcrumb NavXT 5.1.1 -->
    Realia
                                                        </div><!-- /.breadcrumb -->

                                                                    <div class="account pull-right">
                                                                <div class="menu-anonymous-container"><ul id="menu-anonymous" class="nav nav-pills"><li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="login/index.html">Login</a></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="Resgister" CssClass="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123" NavigateUrl="~/register.aspx" runat="server">Register</asp:HyperLink></li>

    </ul></div>

                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.span12 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.breadcrumb-wrapper -->

                        <!-- HEADER -->
                        <div id="header-wrapper">
                            <div id="header">
                                <div id="header-inner">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="navbar">
                                            <div class="navbar-inner">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="logo-wrapper span4">
                                                        <a href="#nav" id="btn-nav">Toggle navigation</a>

                                                                                                            <div class="logo">
                                                                                                                        <a href="index.html" title="Home">
                                                                                                                                                                                        <img src="wp-content/themes/realia/assets/img/logo.png" alt="Home">
                                                                                                                        </a>
                                                        </div><!-- /.logo -->

  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="site-name">
                                                                    <a href="index.html" title="Home" class="brand">
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </div><!-- /.site-name -->

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="site-slogan">
                                                                    <span>Real estate & Rental <br>made easy</span>
                                                                </div><!-- /.site-slogan -->
                                                                                                                                                                </div><!-- /.logo-wrapper -->

                                                                                                        <div class="info">
                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="site-email">
                                                                    <a href="mailto:info@byaviators.com">
                                                                        info@byaviators.com
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </div><!-- /.site-email -->

                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="site-phone">
                                                                    <span>333-444-555</span>
                                                                </div><!-- /.site-phone -->
                                                                                                                </div><!-- /.info -->


                                                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large list-your-property arrow-right"
                                                            href="my-properties/index.html">
                                                            List your property
                                                        </a>
                                                                                                </div><!-- /.row -->
                                            </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
                                        </div><!-- /.navbar -->
                                    </div><!-- /.container -->
                                </div><!-- /#header-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /#header -->
                        </div><!-- /#header-wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- /.top -->
                </div><!-- /.top-wrapper -->

                <!-- NAVIGATION -->
                <div id="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navigation-wrapper">
                            <div class="navigation clearfix-normal">
                                <div class="menu-main-container">
                                    <ul id="menu-main" class="nav">
                                        <li id="menu-item-355" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-355">
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="NavHome" NavigateUrl="~/Index.aspx" runat="server">Home</asp:HyperLink>
                                          </li>
                                       <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menuparent menu-item-78"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavSale" NavigateUrl="~/properties.aspx" runat="server">Sale</asp:HyperLink>

                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="blog/index.html">Apartment</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="right-sidebar/index.html">Commercial</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="login/index.html">Residential</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="left-sidebar/index.html">Land</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="register/index.html">All</a></li>
                                           </ul>

                                      </li>
                                      <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menuparent menu-item-78"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavPurchase" NavigateUrl="~/properties.aspx" runat="server">Purchase</asp:HyperLink>

                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="blog/index.html">Apartment</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="right-sidebar/index.html">Commercial</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="login/index.html">Residential</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="left-sidebar/index.html">Land</a></li>
                                                <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="register/index.html">All</a></li>
                                           </ul>

                                      </li>
                                      <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-56"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavAgents" NavigateUrl="~/agents.aspx" runat="server">Agents</asp:HyperLink>
                                      </li>
                                      <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-56">
                                            <a href="agents/index.html">Construction</a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavContact" NavigateUrl="~/contact-us.aspx" runat="server">Contact us</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                </ul>

                                </div>

                                <div id="icl_lang_sel_widget" class="widget icl_languages_selector"><div id="lang_sel"  >
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="lang_sel_sel icl-en">

                <img  class="iclflag" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/en.png" alt="en"  title="English" />                                
                &nbsp;English</a>                                    
                <ul>
                                                    <li class="icl-fr">          
                        <a rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="fr/index.html">

                        <img  class="iclflag" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/fr.png" alt="fr" title="Français" />&nbsp;                    
                                            Français                    </a>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="icl-de">          
                        <a rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="de/index.html">

                        <img  class="iclflag" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/de.png" alt="de" title="Deutsch" />&nbsp;                    
                                            Deutsch                    </a>
                    </li>
                                </ul>            

                        </li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
    </div>                                                                                                                </div><!-- /.navigation -->
                        </div><!-- /.navigation-wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- /.container -->
                </div><!-- /.navigation -->


        <!-- /.map -->
    </div><!-- /.map-wrapper -->        </div><!-- /.top-inner -->

            </div>


    </body>
```

c# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: its ample amount of code.

Comment: Narrow it down to the smallest amount we can reproduce it.

Comment: are you talking about the .cs or .aspx file?

Comment: aspx, and the header from the c#

Comment: Can you access the controls you copied over? Visual Studio tends to refuse generating controls in designer file when it cannot analyze the markup. In this case it could help if you paste the stuff you want to copy into notepad first - and then paste it into the webform. This procedure will get rid of most of the "invisible" control commands, which could exist in the source file.

Comment: Where is the aspx header?

Comment: the whole html code is in .aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code I see no header in your ASPX file. It should be something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" %>
```

This maps the ASPX file and the CS file together into one (hence the `partial` part in your code behind class declaration).

Comment: you are right this code is not available in this file but i added it now and its underlined blue whith a message "Keyword is not valid as an identifier"

Comment: Where is the error? Also, maybe you need to hit compile first.

Comment: when i hover the arrow over this scrip it shows this message

Comment: and how do i hit the compiler...??

Comment: Press the run button in VS. On what line is the error?

Comment: Try to create a new aspx file and copy your html to it, but leave the first line of the ASPX intact.

Comment: thanks its done...i amde a new aspx file and pasted the code in it under the header.

Comment: Okay. You could try to see what was missing from that other file now, but at least, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't set the `runat="server"` tag. Without that, the CodeBehind doesn't know the controls at all.

Comment: when i drag the item in the design or .aspx file the runat="server" is present in that tag by default and still i have that problem